# Change color of selected map feature in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I would like to change the color of the currently selected feature in my d3.js map.  However, my code changes the color of every feature I click.  How do I reset the map such that when I click on one feature, all other features previously clicked would reset to the default colors?  Below is my code.  Color change happens on the "click" function:

```
function ready(error, us) {
    svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.ecol3_wgs84).features)
    .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("transform", "scale(" + SCALE + ")") //scale the map
        .attr("class", "region")
        .attr("ecoregion", function (d, i) {
            return us.objects.ecol3_wgs84.geometries[i].properties.US_L3NAME;
        })
        .attr("d", path)
       .on("mouseover", function (d) {
           d3.select("h3").text(d.properties.US_L3NAME);
           d3.select(this).attr("class", "region hover");
       })
       .on("mouseout", function (d) {
           d3.select("h3").text("");
           d3.select(this).attr("class", "region");
       })
       .on("click", function (d) {
           var name = d.properties.US_L3NAME;
           var region = d3.select("#regName");               
           region.property("value", name);

           d3.select(this).style("fill", getColor(name));
       });
}

function getColor(n) {
    var selectedRegion = "";
    selectedRegion = $("#regName").val();        

    if (n == selectedRegion) {
        return 'orange';
    }
    else {
        return '#005DAA';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In the click event you can reset all the other features to their default state, and then set the clicked feature to the desired style:

```
   .on("click", function (d) {
      svg.selectAll('path').attr('class','region');
      d3.select(this).attr('class','selected');
    })
```

Creating a class style for selected of course. *As far as I am aware, if you apply a style with selection.style, it will override your css styles, this is why I am proposing a solution here that only uses classes. But this has given me an idea for an alternative solution that requires very little modification of your code, see below*

The primary problem though, is that when you mouse off of it, you will reset the clicked feature to the default style:

```
   .on("mouseout", function (d) {
       d3.select("h3").text("");
       d3.select(this).attr("class", "region");
   })
```

And since a click must happen before mouse out, you will lose your click style once the mouse moves.

Combining both mouseover/mouseoff and click can be difficult to get the desired behaviour in all situations.

You'll need to:

1. Remove the event listener for mouseout from the clicked feature, but put it back after it is no longer "clicked" or active.
2. Remove the mouseover listener for the clicked feature, but put it back after it is no longer "clicked". Otherwise, mouseover will change your style once you mouse over the clicked feature, which is easy when dealing with small features or irregularly drawn features like ecoregions/zones.

Removing is easy to do when the click event happens:

```
d3.select(this).on('mouseout',null)
```

It is a little bit more work to add the listeners back when the next feature is clicked.

To do so will change your code a little. I'll show a potential solution here, but removing the references to changing the input box and header so it is a little cleaner:

```
 .on("mouseover", function (d) {
     d3.select(this).attr("class", "region hover");
     d3.select(this).on("mouseout", function(d) {
         d3.select(this).attr("class", "region");
     })
 })
 .on("click", function (d) {
     svg.selectAll('path').attr('class','region'); // ensure every other feature is set to default
     d3.selectAll('path').on("mouseover", function (d) { // add a mouseover event to every feature in order to get the last one clicked
         d3.select(this).attr("class", "region hover"); 
         d3.select(this).on("mouseout", function(d) {
             d3.select(this).attr("class", "region"); // add a mouseout event to every feature on mouseover
         });
     });
     d3.select(this).on("mouseout", null); // cancel mouseover out events for the clicked feature.
     d3.select(this).on('mouseover',null);
     d3.select(this).attr('class','selected');
 });
```

[I packaged up an example here, with your geographic features](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/f5b4227c93d197d69cf73e62c73afef3). You could clean it up by using a function for the mouseover functionality, this part is essentially repeated. Lastly, there are probably superior ways of achieving this goal, this is just one. This should, however, demonstrate how you could set up your event listeners so that they do not conflict with one another and you get the results you are looking for.

---

Faster solution: (referenced above)

You should be able to modify the click function to strip any fill style applied with selection.style from other clicked elements, and after, apply it to the clicked feature:

```
   .on("click", function (d) {
       d3.selectAll('path').style('fill',null);
       d3.select(this).style("fill","orange")
   });
```

This should work with the code you've posted above.

Comment: Once again, you saved me.  This works perfectly for my purposes.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help, I find I learn well by trying to tackle problems such as these. If the answer works for you, it doesn't hurt anyone to indicate it by accepting so that others stumbling across this know the answer worked.

Comment: Wow!  The second one is even better!  Thanks once again.

Comment: @AndrewReid welcome to StackOverflow. Nobody upvotes, OP doesn't upvote (in his/her case he/she can't, rp<15), OP doesn't accept the answer... you're lucky if you get a "thanks, it worked". Sometimes I think I'm the only one upvoting here... but that's in the past now! :)

Comment: Yeah, I know, think I saw a post on meta on this topic by someone... In any event, I am learning while attempting to explain, suits my primary purpose here at least. And it seems I succeded in a solution here whatever the form.

Comment: Indeed. I like S.O. because, by answering the questions, I end up building a database of solutions to myself, which I already used for solving problems in my actual jobs (when you say to yourself "hey, I've solved this problem before!"): I simply search my previous answers and find the code. Ops, I upvoted you. Sorry for that.